# What are Pandas "expanding window" functions?

Tags: pandas

Pandas documentation lists a bunch of "expanding window functions" :

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/api.html#standard-expanding-window-functions

But I couldn't figure out what they do from the documentation. Are they equivalent to the rolling functions, but dropping the NA values?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You may want to read [this Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html#expanding-window):

> A common alternative to rolling statistics is to use an expanding
> window, which yields the value of the statistic with **all the data
> available up to that point in time**.
>
> These follow a similar interface to .rolling, with the .expanding
> method returning an Expanding object.
>
> As these calculations are a special case of rolling statistics, they
> are implemented in pandas such that the following two calls are
> equivalent:

```
In [96]: df.rolling(window=len(df), min_periods=1).mean()[:5]
Out[96]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.314226 -0.001675  0.071823  0.892566
2000-01-02  0.654522 -0.171495  0.179278  0.853361
2000-01-03  0.708733 -0.064489 -0.238271  1.371111
2000-01-04  0.987613  0.163472 -0.919693  1.566485
2000-01-05  1.426971  0.288267 -1.358877  1.808650

In [97]: df.expanding(min_periods=1).mean()[:5]
Out[97]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.314226 -0.001675  0.071823  0.892566
2000-01-02  0.654522 -0.171495  0.179278  0.853361
2000-01-03  0.708733 -0.064489 -0.238271  1.371111
2000-01-04  0.987613  0.163472 -0.919693  1.566485
2000-01-05  1.426971  0.288267 -1.358877  1.808650
```

Comment: So it's a rolling operation with the window as the full length of the dataframe.  I don't see why there needs to be a separate function for this...

Comment: It's actually very useful, because rolling operations are for fixed window sizes. However, this operation is an expanding window size. It starts with a "rolling" window of length 1 period, the next window size is 2 periods, then 3, 4, 5, etc. For streaming data a rolling window of the full length of the original dataframe will start to drop the first couple of observations, whereas the expanding window allows you to add new data.

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, but I really didn't see pandas can handle steaming data.Google found nothing , could you show us an example ?

Comment: Is this only applicable for processing values in a single Dataframe? What options are available for a cumulative std if you instantiate a new Dataframe for every batch of data you load?

Answer (score 33):

Those illustrations from Uber explain the concepts very well:

**Expanding window**
[image]

**Sliding window**

[image]

Original article: https://eng.uber.com/omphalos/

Answer (score 31):

To sum up the difference between rolling and expanding function in one line:
In rolling function the window size remain constant whereas in the expanding function it changes.

Example:
Suppose you want to predict the weather, you have 100 days of data:

1. Rolling: let's say window size is 10. For first prediction, it will use (the previous) 10 days of data and predict day 11. For next prediction, it will use the 2nd day (data point) to 11th day of data.
2. Expanding: For first prediction it will use 10 days of data. However, for second prediction it will use **10 + 1 days** of data. The window has therefore "expanded."

   - Window size expands continuously in later method.

Code example:

```
sums = series.expanding(min_periods=2).sum()
```

`series` contains data of number of previously downloaded apps over time series.
Above written code line sum all the number of downloaded apps till that time.

Note: `min_periods=2` means that we need at least 2 previous data points to aggregate over. Our aggregate here is the sum.

Answer (score 1):

The `expanding` function is similar to cumulative functions like `cumsum`, `cumprod`,  `cummin` etc., but the first n values in `expanding` can be skipped. If we set the parameter `min_periods` to 1 and don't skip any values, we get the same result with `.expanding(1).sum()` as with `.cumsum()`. Here is the comparison between rolling, expanding and cumulative sums:

```
   col rolling(3).sum() expanding(3).sum()           cumsum()
0   10              NaN                NaN                 10
1   20              NaN                NaN              10+20
2   30         10+20+30           10+20+30           10+20+30
3   40         20+30+40        10+20+30+40        10+20+30+40
4   50         30+40+50     10+20+30+40+50     10+20+30+40+50
5   60         40+50+60  10+20+30+40+50+60  10+20+30+40+50+60
```

Note that in both cases, `rolling` and `expanding`, we start from the third row because our window size is 3 and we need at least 3 values for the first calculation (all rows before that get `NaN`). The size of the rolling window remains constant, and the window moves down one step after each iteration. In contrast, the expanding window doesn't move, but increases its size by adding a next value after each iteration, like in `cumsum`.