# Can RollingOLS in statsmodels.regression.rolling do an expanding window regression?

Tags: python

Hi does anybody know if the RollingOLS module can do an expanding window regression. It seems to me natural if one specifies a min_nobs number and then specifies a either a very large number (>=len(y)) or just len(y) as window (where y is the dependent variable) then the module should be able to produce expanding regression result from min_nobs to len(y). Is that not the case? I tried to use expanding=True option but it gives me an error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, expanding window is equivalent to rolling window with `window=n_rows`, `min_periods=1`.
Hence if you can set both to the correct values you get an "expanding" window OLS.

Take also a look here, basically `pd.DataFrame.expanding` is implemented in terms of `pd.DataFrame.rolling`.

[What are Pandas "expanding window" functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370666/what-are-pandas-expanding-window-functions)

Comment: Let's say I have a dependent variable Y that has 100 observations, and two explanatory variables, do I set window=100 and min_periods=3 (the minimum number of observations needed to do estimation)? When I do this, I only get one set of estimation parameters for the last date instead of, say, 97 sets of parameters. Could you explain in more detail?