# Pandas - Replace NaNs in a column with the mean of specific group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with data like the following. The dataframe is sorted by the date:

```
category  value  Date
0         1      24/5/2019     
1         NaN    24/5/2019         
1         1      26/5/2019       
2         2      1/6/2019      
1         2      23/7/2019       
2         NaN    18/8/2019         
2         3      20/8/2019       
7         3      1/9/2019 
1         NaN    12/9/2019       
2         NaN      13/9/2019
```

I would like to replace the "NaN" values with the previous mean for that specific category.

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Some approaches I considered:

1) This litte riff:

```
   df['mean' = df.groupby('category')['time'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean()))
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799279/10636514)

This gets me the the correct means in but in another column, and it does not replace the NaNs.

2) This riff replaces the NaNs with the average of the columns:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis = 1).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618322/10636514)

Both of these do not exactly give what I want. If someone could guide me on this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you exactly mean with the "previous mean for that specific category"? Because the category's repeat.

Comment: By this i mean, for every NaN value, look at the corresponding category, find the mean of that category across all previous dates, then replace the NaN with this calculated mean value.

Comment: `df['value']=df['value'].fillna(df.groupby('category')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean()))`?

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `value` by new Series from `shift` + `expanding` + `mean`, first value of `1` group is not replaced, because no previous `NaN` values exits:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
s = df.groupby('category')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean())
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(s)
print (df)
   category  value       Date
0         0    1.0 2019-05-24
1         1    NaN 2019-05-24
2         1    1.0 2019-05-26
3         2    2.0 2019-01-06
4         1    2.0 2019-07-23
5         2    2.0 2019-08-18
6         2    3.0 2019-08-20
7         7    3.0 2019-01-09
8         1    1.5 2019-12-09
9         2    2.5 2019-09-13
```

Comment: Thanks this is some awesome python magic. Helped me learn a few new ways to do things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pandas.Series.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace NaN values:

```
df['value']=df['value'].fillna(df.groupby('category')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean()))
print(df)

   category  value       Date
0         0    1.0  24/5/2019
1         1    NaN  24/5/2019
2         1    1.0  26/5/2019
3         2    2.0   1/6/2019
4         1    2.0  23/7/2019
5         2    2.0  18/8/2019
6         2    3.0  20/8/2019
7         7    3.0   1/9/2019
8         1    1.5  12/9/2019
9         2    2.5  13/9/2019
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great way to approach it, I learnt something new here!

Comment: would you appreciate if you voted positive @ConvexLeopard

Comment: Sure, I have upvoted (apologies didn't know I could upvote). Thanks for your help!