# Sliding Window Groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How do use a groupby to do a sliding window for a calculation in Pandas? Imagine I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'data': [1,10,2,4,3,4,5,6]})


df
  type  data
0    A     1
1    A     10
2    A     2
3    A     4
4    B     3
5    B     4
6    B     5
7    B     6
```

and for every `type` in the dataframe I want to determine the standard deviation between the 1st and 3rd row (and only those, ignoring the data in row 2), on a sliding scale. This means for the A's I'd want to use these rows to find the first std dev:

```
  type  data
0    A     1    <----
1    A     10
2    A     2    <----
3    A     4
```

then on these:

```
  type  data
0    A     1    
1    A     10   <----
2    A     2
3    A     4   <----
```

and so on, repeated for the other types in this example. You can assume that there are a lot more than 4 types and more than 4 rows for each type. Is there a way to do something like this with groupby? I know this is doable with `iloc`, but I was hoping there was a more elegant and standard way with groupby or some other pandas function. I'm hoping there is something like this that will work . . .

```
df.groupby(df.type).sliding_window(slide=2).std()
```

EDIT: It seems rolling will not work. I want ONLY the endpoints used for `std()`, not the whole window. As an example, the first calculation should be `std([1, 2])` because we'll be looking at index 0 and 2 exclusively and ignoring the value in index 1.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996302/python-rolling-functions-for-groupby-object

Comment: perhaps the solution is the same (potentially) but that result did not come up when searching for pandas groupby sliding window

Comment: also, it now seems rolling does not work, so probably not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

#### `rolling`

```
df.groupby('type').rolling(3).std()

        data
type        
A    0   NaN
     1   NaN
     2   1.0
     3   1.0
B    4   NaN
     5   NaN
     6   1.0
     7   1.0
```

Comment: That output doesnt look correct. I'd expected to see a value at indexes 0 and 1, not at 2 and 3.

Comment: it looks like adding a .shift(-2) to the end will work. If there is a better way, let me know

Comment: actually @piRSquared, this wont work, my fault for picking bad example data. The rolling function uses the entire window for the std() calculation, i want to use ONLY indexes 0, and 2, it seems rolling does just what it says, a rolling calculation, using everything in the window. I only want to use the extremes/endpoints

Comment: also, if this were only using the correct values I'd expect the std to be ~1.41. I updated the question so the numbers are more extreme.

Comment: `df.groupby('type').rolling(2).std()` gives you the `~1.41`

Comment: when I run with the original dataframe, (with window 2), I get 0.707 for every row (except the first in the window, which is NaN). I don't think rolling will work, unless I re-organize the dataframe to have the rows I want next to eachother